# How to concat a table and then insert the results in the original table

Tags: sql-server, select, casting, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [ABCDEF],
    RIGHT(CONCAT('0', [ABCDEF), 6) AS ABCDEFnew
FROM 
    dbo.Table1
```

Now I would like to return `ABCDEFnew` into `dbo.Table1`.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Add 'INTO' with new table name before the `FROM` and remove '`[ABCDEF]' from the `SELECT`

Comment: You want to add it as a new row, or update the existing row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append to an existing table try something like:

```
INSERT INTO
    dbo.Table2
SELECT
    [ABCDEF],
    RIGHT(CONCAT('0', [ABCDEF), 6)
FROM
    dbo.Table1
```

This assumes that `Table2` has the same columns as `Table1` otherwise you would to need to add the column names.

To create a new table try something like:

```
SELECT     
    RIGHT(CONCAT('0', [ABCDEF), 6) AS ABCDEFnew
INTO
    dbo.NewTable
FROM 
    dbo.Table1
```

And to update the original table use something like (but not recommended - see below):

```
UPDATE
    T1
SET
    T1.ABCDEFnew = RIGHT(CONCAT('0', [ABCDEF), 6)
FROM
    dbo.Table1 AS T1
```

Or, as suggested by Smor

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.UpdatedTable1
AS
SELECT 
    [ABCDEF],
    RIGHT(CONCAT('0', [ABCDEF), 6) AS ABCDEFnew
FROM 
    dbo.Table1
```

Comment: Hi thanks! Is there also an easy way to directly write is as a column in the old Table (dbo.Table1)?

Comment: This is starting to sound like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you just need to add a computed column to the existing table using your expression? A view would also accomplish the same goal. Typically we try to avoid storing the same information twice in a database.

Comment: @SMor I've updated the answer to  include your suggestion of  view, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am still a beginner so I think I have to look further in some of your suggestions ;-). Kind regards, Nick

Comment: @Nick No problem - we've all been there. If you found the answer helpful then you could accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the SELECT INTO be an INSERT INTO? I thought SELECT INTO was used to create a new table and insert at the same time. In this case, the OP has an existing table, as he suggest in the question title: "insert the results in the original table".

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey Good point, I've updated the answer to cover both scenarios